# Get Index of Specific Content Control based on ID or Title

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I would like to retrieve the word content control's index via VBA given a specific title without having to loop through all content controls looking for the title.

I know the title of the content control that I would like to select therefore I can set the ID of that specific content control to a variable for instance

```
a = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("123").Item(1).ID
```

Now, I would like to know what the index of this item is among the other content controls in the document (over 450 content controls in the file template) such that I can refer to the content control index as a variable.

In lay terms I would like something along the lines of "b=getIndexOfA(a)" such that I can perform later process such as:

```
for i=b to ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Count
    .....
next i
```

I am running Word 2016 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach works for just about object in the document body that's part of the text (as opposed to a floating image). Get a `Range` for the object, then set its starting point to the beginning of the document. Count all the objects of that type within the range:

```
Dim lIndexCC as Long
Dim cc as Word.ContentControl
Dim rng as Word.Range

Set cc = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("123").Item(1)
Set rng = cc.Range
rng.Start = ActiveDocument.Content.Start
lIndexCC = rng.ContentControls.Count
Debug.Print lIndexCC
```